# Antd react customize directrory tree node background?

Tags: reactjs, npm, antd

How to change the default background color of antd directory tree node when mouseover the tree node using less styles ?

```
 <Tree.DirectoryTree>
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Tree.TreeNode
              // @ts-ignore
              item={item}
              icon={<></>}
              key={item.user_folder_id}
              title={item.title}
            >
              {item?.data.map((node) => {
                return (
                  <Tree.TreeNode
                    node={node}
                    key={node.node_id}
                    title={ node.title }
                  ></Tree.TreeNode>
                );
              })}

            </Tree.TreeNode>
          );
        })}
      </Tree.DirectoryTree>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <Tree.DirectoryTree className="custom-tree">
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Tree.TreeNode
              // @ts-ignore
              item={item}
              icon={<></>}
              key={item.user_folder_id}
              title={item.title}
            >
              {item?.data.map((node) => {
                return (
                  <Tree.TreeNode
                    node={node}
                    key={node.node_id}
                    title={ node.title }
                  ></Tree.TreeNode>
                );
              })}

            </Tree.TreeNode>
          );
        })}
      </Tree.DirectoryTree>
```

styles.less

```less
.custom-tree .ant-tree-treenode:hover::before {
  background: blue !important;
}
```